# working outside of aplication context in flask with a self made decorator

Tags: python, flask, decorator, python-decorators

I'm doing a blog for my self from scratch and everything is working, even the sessions.

Now I'm trying to limit the admin with a decorator called `@require_login`. I think I'm doing something really wrong, besides the fact that is not working.

Here is my decorator:

```
def requirir_login(func):
    request = make_response()
    if session['logged_in'] == True:

        return func
    else: 
        print("no hay sesion registrada webon")
```

and here is it used, decorating the admin function:

```
@app.route("/admin")
@requirir_login
def admin():
    users = User.objects

    return render_template("admin.html", users=users)
```

My logic behind this is to check if there is a session then return the admin function. If not I wanted to check in the terminal that message for test purposes.

I haven't decided what to do if there is not a session yet. I would possibly redirect to the log-in page or something.

Comment: You could use this instead of reinventing your own.. https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: i see... i've never heard of this thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your decorator needs to provide a *wrapper* function, which will be called in place of the decorated function. Only when that wrapper is being called is an actual request being routed and can you test the session:

```
from functools import wraps

def requirir_login(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if session['logged_in']:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        else: 
            print("no hay sesion registrada webon")
    return wrapper
```

When a decorator is applied, it is called an its *return value* replaces the decorated function. Here `wrapper` is returned, so that now becomes your view function.

The wrapper passes on all arguments untouched, making your decorator suitable for any view function regardless of the arguments they expect to be passed in from the route.

I also made a few other changes to improve the functionality of your decorator:

- You don't need to test for `== True`; that is what `if` is *for*, to test if the result of an expression is true or not.
- I used the [`@functools.wraps()` decorator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) to give your wrapper the same name and documentation string as the original wrapped view function, always helpful when debugging.

You could indeed use a redirect to the login form if you have one:

```
return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

if your login view is named `login`.